# Preload WSGI app with child update of parent data structures and respawn of workers?

Tags: shared-memory, reload, wsgi, preload

[Preload](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=preload#preload-app) of `WSGI` in, for example, `gunicorn`, permits shared read-only RAM-resident data structures in the parent process, prior to pre-forking worker processes.

How can a worker process queue up a modification to its parent's data structure, so that the parent makes the modification to the shared data structure and then re-spawns the worker processes with the new data?

A use case:

- resource-intensive preload
- high frequency reads
- rare writes
- writes involving complex memory allocation operations. i.e. the `multiprocess` preallocation of a block of memory in, say, an array, isn't really  adequate due to non-trivial memory allocations.